# Fast forwarding is removed automatically on server after git pull

Tags: git, github

Git Fast forwarding is removed automatically on server during SYNC after we `reset head` and `git pull` to keep the SYNC with git branch. It works fine onetime if we run `git checkout <branch>`. issue comes again after running `git reset --hard <branchname>` and `git pull` (used for SYNC process), fast forwarding is removed and server directory shows one commit behind. what could be reason for this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your "SYNC" step consists of ?

Comment: sudo rsync -avz --exclude storage --exclude /vendor --exclude .env --exclude '.git*' --delete sourcedirectory/ targetdirectory/ 2>&1 && sudo chown -R :apache /var/www/directoryname/ 2>&1

--- Checkout & sync
Executing: cd /sourcedirectory && `git reset --hard origin/branchname` && `git pull`
Result: 
* 
---------- UPLOAD
Executing: cd /sourcedirectory && `git reset --hard` origin//sourcedirectory && `git pull`
Result: 
* sending incremental file list
* 
* sent 46486 bytes  received 222 bytes  93416.00 bytes/sec
* total size is 59059575  speedup is 1264.44

 SYNC FINISHED

Comment: when we do `git checkout` as explained in question, we get the result is `* Fast-forward
* sending incremental file list
* public/
* public/test.php
* 
* sent 46405 bytes  received 243 bytes  93296.00 bytes/sec
* total size is 58746626  speedup is 1259.36`

 SYNC FINISHED
but in next sync it is not fast forwarding and also not syncing the directory